# Swift / CoreLocation : North heading from didUpdateLocation

Tags: swift, cllocationmanager, location-services, cllocationdistance

Is it the way to get heading from inside the `didUpdateLocation` method ? I am grapple with task which is about sending the data about user location to container class called `Ping`. The Ping class have to contain basics user location as well as with `north heading`.

- Is it the way to enable compass from code in iOS ?

My location service saving the data after period of `time` or `degree turn` of the device or `distance traveled` - also if we turn faster or we traveled the distance then timer going to be restarted.

I have not test it yet on physical device ( only simulator ) so I am not able to see If I am counting well traveled distance and the angle.

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation
import CoreMotion
import UIKit

class LocationService: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var _locationManager: CLLocationManager!
    var _motionManager: CMMotionManager!
    var _timer = Timer()
    var _heading: Double!
    var _accuracy: Double!
    var _latitude: Double!
    var _longitude: Double!
    var _velocity: Double!
    var _startLocation: CLLocation!
    var _lastLocation: CLLocation!
    var _traveledDistance: Double = 0
    var _seconds = 0
    var _deferringUpdates: Bool = false

    static let _instance : LocationService = LocationService()

    public static var Instance : LocationService {
        get{ return _instance}
    }

    public func InitLocationManager() {

        _locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        _locationManager.delegate = self
        _locationManager.distanceFilter = 1000
        _locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer
        _locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        _locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        if CLLocationManager.headingAvailable() {

            _locationManager.headingFilter = 5
            _locationManager.startUpdatingHeading()
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading _newHeading: CLHeading) {

        if _newHeading.headingAccuracy < 0 {
            return
        }

        let _theHeading : CLLocationDirection = _newHeading.trueHeading > 0 ? _newHeading.trueHeading : _newHeading.magneticHeading

        self._heading = _theHeading
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations _locations: [CLLocation]) {

        let _location = _locations[0]

        self._accuracy = _location.horizontalAccuracy
        self._latitude = _location.coordinate.latitude
        self._longitude = _location.coordinate.longitude
        self._velocity = _location.speed

        _timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(UpdateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        if _startLocation == nil {
            _startLocation = _locations.first
        } else {
            if let _lastLocation = _locations.last {
                let _distance = _startLocation.distance(from: _lastLocation)
                let _lastDistance = _lastLocation.distance(from: _lastLocation)
                _traveledDistance += _lastDistance

                if _traveledDistance <= 100 {
                    PostNotificationWithLocation()
                    _traveledDistance = 0
                    _timer.invalidate()
                }
            }
        }
        _lastLocation = _locations.last

        _motionManager = CMMotionManager()
        if _motionManager?.isDeviceMotionAvailable == true {
            _motionManager?.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.1

            let queue = OperationQueue()

            _motionManager?.startDeviceMotionUpdates(to: queue, withHandler: { (_motion, _error) in
                if let attitude = _motion?.attitude {
                    if(attitude.pitch == 30/M_PI) {
                        self.PostNotificationWithLocation()
                        self._timer.invalidate()
                    }
                }
            })
        }

        _locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func PostNotificationWithLocation() -> Void {
         NotificationCenter.default.post(name: LOCATION_NOTIFICATION, object: nil, userInfo: ["latitude":_latitude, "longitude":_longitude, "velocity":_velocity, "traveledDistance":_traveledDistance])
    }

    func UpdateTimer() {
        _seconds += 1
        if _seconds == 10 {
            PostNotificationWithLocation()
            _timer.invalidate()
            _seconds = 0
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: You might want to consider using _location.course which gives you the direction based on gps coordinates. The magnetic heading can lose accuracy in my experience.